# Excel VBA hanging when pasting Pivot table over itself

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, copy-paste

The following code hangs when I try to paste the pivot table over itself. I've used exactly the same code earlier but it doesn't work here. I've run through it step by step to find the problem. Below is the whole code with the problem in bold close to the end of the code. I've added the whole code in case someone can see any problems higher up, which I doubt since it runs smoothly up to the pasting at the end.

```
'Create Pivot Store Stock Issues

Dim RowCount As Long
Dim wsIssues As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim lastRow As Long

Set wsIssues = Worksheets.Add
    RowCount = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(51, 1).End(xlDown).Row
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "Summary!R51C1:R" & RowCount & "C38")
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(wsIssues.Range("A3"))

    'Speeds up code dramatically
    pt.ManualUpdate = True

    With pt.PivotFields("Site")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Ownership")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Article")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 4
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Article Description")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 5
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Promo")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 6
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Caption = " "
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Vendor")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 7
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Pack Size")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 8
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With

    wsIssues.PivotTables(1).Name = "StockIssues"

    With pt.PivotFields("MS")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 9
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
        .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="4"
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Listing Status")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 10
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
        .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="Listed"
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("RP Type")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 11
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
        .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="Roster"
    End With

    With pt.PivotFields("OOS NO SOO")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 12
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("OOS SOO")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 13
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("SOH NO SOO")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 14
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Negative Stock")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 15
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Overstock")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 16
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Dormant Stock")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 17
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Outdated Stock Counts")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 18
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With
    With pt.PivotFields("Total Issues")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 19
        .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    End With

    With pt
        .ShowDrillIndicators = False
        .InGridDropZones = True
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    End With

    pt.RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels

    With pt
        .ColumnGrand = False
        .RowGrand = False
    End With

    pt.ManualUpdate = False

    With wsIssues.PivotTables("StockIssues").TableRange2
        .Copy
        **.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues**
    End With

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
```

Comment: That same copy/paste approach works fine for me: maybe try adding a DoEvents just before the copy, to make sure the pivottable is complete.

Comment: think about de-cluttering your code by using a variable for the `Array(False, False, False .....`

Answer (score 0):

I've ran your code with slight modification, and it worked just fine:

```
' already defined and set the pt object, why not use it
pt.TableRange2.Copy '<-- copy the TableRange2 of the Pivot-Table

' paste to range "A3"
wsIssues.Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```